# Concatenate numpy array in new dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a 2D matrix, that each datapoint is a 2D array.

      `/         10      \
 /   |a1_0|a2_0|a3_0|....|
     |a1_1|..............|
1000 |a1_2|..............| 
     |...................|
 \   |...................|`

where `a1_0`, `a1_1`, `a2_0` are all (1025, 16) array.

To my understanding, that means I have to create a matrix with `shape = (10, 1000, 1025, 16)`. (please let me know if I'm wrong)

And all I have are `a1_0`, `a1_1`, `a2_0`...

So my question is how to concatenate these arrays with most efficient ways if I have to concatenate 2 numpy array into a new dimension?

I've tried `np.vstack()` and `np.concatenate()` but seem not right.

---

I am using a function to transfer a piece of audio into a spectrogram (which is a picture), the function will return a variable called `spec`, which is a (1025, 16) numpy array

Therefore, at first I was trying to do:

```
for a0 ~ a9, concatenate:
   for a1_1 ~ a1_999, concatenate:
       spec = gen_spectrogram (audio)
```

Comment: How are all these arrays stored?

Comment: I am using a function to transfer a piece of audio into a spectrogram (which is a picture), the function will return a variable spec, which is a (1025, 16) numpy array

Comment: Initialize array `out` with shape : `(10, 1000, 1025, 16)` and then iteratively assign : `out[i,j] = ..`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand with the `out` thing, is it a numpy method?

Comment: @Divakar Are you suggesting that I can create an empty array with shape `(10, 1000, 1025, 16)` and then iteratively assign last 2 numbers?

Comment: and then iteratively assign into first two axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First stack ai_0, ..., ai_999:

```
ci = np.stack([ai_0,...,ai_999])
```

Then stack c0, ..., c9

```
conc = np.stack([c0, ..., c9])
```

The result should be of shape (10, 1000, 1025, 16)